# Play framework- continuous compilation in prod mode

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

There are certain issues I'm facing only in prod mode and not in dev mode.

Is it possible to do a continuous compilation in prod mode? Akin to a `~start`? I want to avoid having to do a `Ctrl-C` every time I want to make a change.

Comment: Why aren't you working in `dev` mode? You shouldn't be hacking on your production code !

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, however, as I mentioned- I'm facing those issues exclusively in prod mode :-(

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible, this is exact difference between the modes.

All you can is adding some more logging to your app and *hunt* for the problem until it's found.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact difference? I would think that the difference was: (1) Having a different mode string (2) Using compiled assets from jars. I don't know of any other fundamental differences. Basically, what I'm looking for is a trigger that would automatically repeat these steps.